# c# regex matches example to extract result

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract a character/digit from a string that is between single quotes and seems like i am failing to write the correct pattern.

Test string - only value that changes is the single character/digit in single quotes

```
[+] Random session part: 'm'
```

I am using the following pattern but it returns empty

```
        var line = "[+] Random session part: 'm'";
        Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<=\')(.*?)(?=\')");
        Match match = pattern.Match(line);
        Debug.Log($"{match.Groups["postfix"].Value}");
        int postFix = int.Parse(match.Groups["postfix"].Value);
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use this regX :

```
'(.)'  // match any string between single quotes
```

show [result](https://regex101.com/r/bOflV9/1)

or

```
(?<=\')(.*?)(?=\') //containing a non-greedy match
```

show [result](https://regex101.com/r/hxwIuq/1)

Answer (score 0):

You have an overly complicated regex, and looking for a group named 'postfix' in you match, while your regex does not have such a named group.

A simpler regex would be:

```
'(.)'
```

This looks for a single character between two single quotes, and has that character wrapped in a capture group. Put a breakpoint after your match row, and you can explore the matched object.

You can explore the regex above with your match here:
https://regexr.com/77b0m

BTW: Your code tries to parse the string "m" into an int, this will throw and error, your should probably handle that case with int.TryParse